# Adding tag and custom post meta

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

The above function then checks for a condition for two scenarios:

**1. Image is selected:** a post is created from the first function when an image is selected. Because it already has the `post_id`, it simply updates the "dummy" content with the real content from the input fields

**2. Image is not selected:**  as an image is not selected, then there is no post created from the first function. Because there is no post (thus no `post_id`), it creates a new post using the input fields.

**Problem:**
There are total 4 input fields that I need to have: title (`title`), description(`content`), tag(`rh_tag`) and custom field (`custom_1`).

I am having a problem with tag and custom field in a scenario when an image is selected (the function is not completed).

So, let say, if I do not select an image (thus no post is created from the first function), then the second function (and "`else`" part) simply creates a new post with all the four input. This works just fine.

However, if I select an image, then I am missing something and I can't somehow make the function work. I tried to add same `$post =array` as the second function, but it was not successful.

Can someone help me out how to "complete" the first function so that I can add tag and custom post meta even when an image is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, look at WordPress codex. As I see, you have incorrect usage of [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). You should use `post_id` as first argument of the function, not `array`

At second, before accessing value from `$_POST` array, be sure that it exists:

```
$customValue = isset($_POST['custom_1']) ? $_POST['custom_1'] : 'default value';
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, I changed those two. However, the two fields (tag and custom_1) are not saved when an image is also uploaded in the post. (meaning, I am not sure what change I need to make to the first function).